# How to execute function after stream is closed in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I am using the [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader) package to upload files to a server and I'd like to execute a function after the upload is complete:

```
final StreamSubscription<UploadTaskProgress> subscription = _uploader.progress.listen(
  (e) {
    print(e.progress);
  },
  onError: (ex, stacktrace) {
    throw Exception("Something went wrong updating the file...");
  },
  onDone: () {
    myFunction(); // won't run
  },
  cancelOnError: true,
);
```

**The problem is** the `onDone` function doesn't execute thus meaning `myFunction` never executes. I've done some digging and I found that `onDone` gets called when we close the stream but there is no such method on the `subscription` variable. I have not used streams much and therefore am pretty bad with them.

**My question is, how can I run `myFunction`? once the stream is complete?** I thought that `onDone` would get called when such is the case but I guess not.

Thank you!

Comment: most likely you should use `_uploader.result` if you want to track upload result

Answer (score 1):

I didn't used that package before but I was reading a litle bit about the package and I think you can execute your funciton inside the main block, the other ones are to handle internal processes like stopping a background job or some other external stuff like notify the error to some error monitoring tool, this is what I propose to you:

```
final StreamSubscription<UploadTaskProgress> subscription = 

_uploader.progress.listen(
  (e) {
    if (e.status is UploadTaskStatus._internal(3)) {
      myFunction()
    }
    print(e.progress);
  },
  onError: (ex, stacktrace) {
    throw Exception("Something went wrong updating the file...");
  },
  cancelOnError: true,
);
```

Just to be clear I'm not sure of the specific implementation, is just and idea I get from the docs, seems like the event also contains an status property which has a constant for when the event is completed
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_uploader/latest/flutter_uploader/UploadTaskProgress/UploadTaskProgress.html
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_uploader/latest/flutter_uploader/UploadTaskStatus-class.html

Hope this helps you :D

Comment: So this works nicely except I had to do `e.status == UploadTaskStatus.complete` and also I used `_uploader.result` instead of `_uploader.progress`. If you can update these please and I'll accept the answer. Thank you!